# DAX expression for aggregation

Tags: excel-formula, dax

Thanks in advance for helping this struggling newbie.

Can this aggregation be done with a single DAX statement?

I need to get to the "50" result using a measure if possible...

[excel data screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhFxb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a DAX measure performing this calculation (replace YourTable with the actual table name):

```
=
SUMX ( 
    VALUES ( YourTable[Item] ),
    MAXX (
        VALUES ( YourTable[Round] ),
        CALCULATE( SUM ( YourTable[Value] ) )
    )
)
```

This measure uses nested iterators SUMX and MAXX to iterate over the Item and Round dimensions.